# update extension without composer

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php

I Installed extension manually without composer.
Now I need to update extension version.

How can I update extension version ?

Do I need to delete extension files and replace it with new version ? or there is better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do following steps.

1. Take Backup of current extension (like zip).
2. Remove the all files.
3. Upload the new version files.
4. Run `caching`, `indexing`, `upgrade` and `deploy` command.

Answer (score 1):

you can just replace the existing files and run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

also you need to make sure the extension is compatible , and place them under app/code with proper naming

normally module maintained with composer gets inside vendor folder

Answer (score 1):

To update extension version just replace old extension with new one and run the following commands :-

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 1):

if you have uploaded the modules via FTP upload and want to update, unfortunately you have to update via FTP.

Save the old module data and possibly the database tables of this module.
Disable the module with the command line
php bin/magento module:disable [modul_name]

Remove the module data from the FTP-server

Upload the new modules to the server and run the following commands.

1. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
4. php bin/magento cache:clean

If you have programmed customizations, you should also implement it afterwards.